# How do you make an autocomplete SlickGrid Editor using JQuery UI 1.9.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slickgrid

I've followed the advice from another question but it isn't working for me. I am using JQuery 1.8.3 and JQuery UI 1.9.2

When I press the arrow keys the autocomplete does not select the next option. Why?

I've tried stopPropagation on every event handler. I've used the keypress, keyup, keydown, handlers. I've even wrapped my input element in a parent tag and put stopPropagation on those events and the arrow keys still don't work on the autocomplete element. They just attempt to change the cell which the validator function then prevents.

```
$input.bind("keydown.nav", function (e) {function AutoCompleteEditor(args) {
        var $input,
                defaultValue,
                scope = this;

        this.init = function () {
                $input = $("<INPUT type=text class='editor-text' />");
                $input.appendTo(args.container)
                        .focus()
                        .select()
                        .autocomplete({
                                delay: 0,
                                minLength: 0,
                                source: args.column.options
                        })
                        .bind("keydown.nav", function (e) {
                                if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT) {
                                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                        e.stopPropagation();
                                } else if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.UP || e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.DOWN) {
                                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                        e.stopPropagation();
                                }
                        })
        };

        this.destroy = function () {
                $input.autocomplete('destroy');
                $input.remove();
        };

        this.focus = function () {
                $input.focus();
        };

        this.getValue = function () {
                return $input.val();
        };

        this.setValue = function (val) {
                $input.val(val);
        };

        this.loadValue = function (item) {
                defaultValue = item[args.column.field] || "";
                $input.val(defaultValue);
                $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
                $input.select();
        };

        this.serializeValue = function () {
                return $input.val();
        };

        this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
                item[args.column.field] = state;
        };

        this.isValueChanged = function () {
                return (!($input.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($input.val() != defaultValue);
        };

        this.validate = function () {
                var val = $input.val();
                return {
                        valid: args.column.options.indexOf(val) > -1,
                        msg: null
                };
        };

        this.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Kendo UI ComboBox as editor for some SlickGrid columns. Please, check what I have done to fix the keyboard navigation behaviour.

First, some code to create the grid and a couple of auxiliary functions:

```
var data = []; // some data
var columns = []; // some columns
var options = {
    editable: true,
    autoEdit: false
};
var grid = new Slick.Grid('#myGrid', data, columns, options);
grid.render();

function editing_keydown(e, args) {
    if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey) {
        if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    }
}

function disableGridCellNavigation() {
    grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(editing_keydown);
};

function enableGridCellNavigation() {
    grid.onKeyDown.unsubscribe(editing_keydown);
};
```

Then, *inside the **editor** code*, I call these functions in the **init** and **destroy** methods:

```
this.init = function() {
    // initialization stuff
    // last line:
    disableGridCellNavigation();
};

this.destroy = function () {
    // termination stuff
    // last line:
    enableGridCellNavigation();
};
```

You can use this solution as a starting point to elaborate yours.

Comment: Note that I am **not** using `.bind("keydown.nav")` anywhere. I don't think it is a good idea to put the whole editor code inside a "bind" call! I recommend to separate one thing from another.

Comment: That doesn't work. The arrow keys never make it to the autocomplete widget, so you cannot select any of the suggestions.

It doesn't matter what you bind the event to, stop propagation just doesn't work.